Ckeditors are rendered as hidden during tests when testing with react testing libraries
I am getting the ckeditor rendered as hidden during tests using react testing library. Here is the sample code of the component and test structure. Component setup:
<FlexGrid item>
        <RichTextEditor
            name='choice'
            onChange={(event) => choiceChange(event)}
            onReady={(editor) => {
            setChoiceEditor(editor);
            choiceEditorRef.current = editor;
            }}
            initData={choice}
            readOnly={editData?.InUse}
        />
Test setup:

let isEdit = true;
const isTranslateActionType = false;
const renderMultipleChoiceScreen = async () =>
waitFor(() =>
    expect(() => {
    render(
        <MultipleChoice
        translations={translations}
        onCancel={jest.fn()}
        onAnother={jest.fn()}
        onDone={jest.fn()}
        editData={editData}
        isEdit={isEdit}
        translationMode={isTranslateActionType}
        />
    );
    }).not.toThrowError()
);


describe('MultipleChoice', () => {
afterEach(cleanup);

it('should render with all fields in Edit Mode, Select Line', async () 
=> {
    await renderMultipleChoiceScreen();

    const btnSelect = document.getElementById('select-question');
    expect(btnSelect).toBeInTheDocument();
    userEvent.click(btnSelect);

    const btnReset = document.getElementById('reset');
    expect(btnReset).toBeInTheDocument();
    userEvent.click(btnReset);

    userEvent.click(btnSelect);

    const btnUpdate = document.getElementById('update');
    expect(btnUpdate).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(btnUpdate).toBeDisabled();
});

tried this way  // CKEDITORS - renders as hidden during tests
expect(
document.querySelectorAll('div[style*="display: none"]').length
).toBe(4);
expect(
document.querySelectorAll('div[style*="visibility: hidden"]').length
).toBe(4);
this works but unable to set the value and test the updated value
